# Could Not update packages in asp.net core project on VS Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, visual-studio-mac

I am getting the following error when I do Project-> Update NuGet Packages.

*Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/buildbundlerminifier/index.json'.
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
  Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket is not connected.
  The socket is not connected
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.all/index.json'.
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
  Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket is not connected.
  The socket is not connected
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/buildbundlerminifier/index.json
  GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.all/index.json
Failed to retrieve information about 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.All' from remote source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.aspnetcore.all/index.json'.*

I tried adding the packages through Project->Manage NuGet Packages.
But get the same error!

[image]

[image: Here is a screenshot of my PM console]

Comment: If you try to open any of the failing urls in a browser, what happens?

Comment: It opens in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out a workaround.

When I run #dotnet restore from the CLI, it works!